# Simple Search DataGrid

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, datagrid

Firstly let me clarify (if the title wasn't clear enough): I'm discussing System.Windows.Controls.DataGrid from the .NET 4.0 Framework, not the toolkit edition.

I have a data grid which i read in from a csv which can change with every load.

I am trying to create a simple search, I have been trying to use;

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/FirefoxLikeSearchWithMVVM.aspx

http://manfred-ramoser.blogspot.com/2009/11/search-highlighting-in-wpf-datagrid.html

and others, but there all seem very complicated for a simple task, can anyone help, just to be clear a filtering system is not want i am after, thank you.

Comment: Yes but my last question was so poorly put together i flagged to be removed and re posted hopefully making more sense and with more research done.

Comment: I think you can Fill the Dataview from CSV ,than Bound that DataView at DataGrid where you can Query the Dataview with SQL Syntax "name like 'John'" .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For my project i did a search function this way : 
    i added a 'FilterResult' Boolean property to the ViewModel of my data. It is implementing NotifyPropertyChanged.
    So i perform the filter on my list of object with simple foreach loop and i set/unset FilterResult
    And in the 'Style' of the DataGridRow i put a Setter on Visibility depending upon this FilterResult

```
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridRow}" x:Key="EventColorRowStyle">
        <Style.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding FilterResult}"  Value="False">
                <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed"/>
            </DataTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
```

This simpler and much faster than using the Filter of a CollectionView, but still i can point you on what msdn says about it : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff407126.aspx